# Laravel API Tutorial PUT Not Updating

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785) which suggests a Resource Controller Laravel API Setup.

Everything is working well in a Resource Controller, I have a fair understanding as to what's going on, but when I get to the update function, I return a successful message but never update the database.

Here it is (verbatim from site):

```
public function update($id)
{
$url = Url::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->find($id);

if ( Request::get('url') )
{
    $url->url = Request::get('url');
}

if ( Request::get('description') )
{
    $url->description = Request::get('description');
}

$url->save();

return Response::json(array(
  'error' => false,
  'message' => 'url updated'),
  // or 'message' => $url),
  200
);
}
```

From a quick look, can you see why it's just returning what is already in the database?  It doesn't even like to change the "updated_at" timestamp Laravel seems to be pretty smart about.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain but it seems like there's a few problems with your code. I would make a few changes.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $url = Url::find($id);
    //Alternatively something like
    /*$url = URL::whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->whereId($id)->first();*/

    if ( Request::has('url') )
    {
        $url->url = Request::get('url');
    }

    if ( Request::has('description') )
    {
        $url->description = Request::get('description');
    }

    $url->save();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'message' => 'url updated'),
    ),
   200
    );
}
```

Comment: No worries, I omitted the second question as it really doesn't pertain to this specific problem.

Comment: Cool, did my suggested changes make any difference?

Comment: If I remove the `if` block and hard-code a string to be passed, like `$url->url = 'asdf'` I can get it to update just fine...  However, `$url->url = Request::get('url');` will just blank out the entry.

Comment: Instead of Request::has() and Request::get(), Try using Input::has() and Input::get(). I didn't pick up on that before but I usually wouldn't use Request for those purposes.

Comment: `Input::has()` and `get()` will also work through `curl` in the console.  I've finally found my issue and it involved the encoding of the data in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem **ended up being the data format that I was sending** with Postman REST Chrome Extension.

Even though I could get away with POST'ing data using the default `form-data` encoding, to PUT data, I had to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` in the options.  I've found a nice resources on SO about this: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

Comment: This **non answer** post should be an edit to your question, instead.